# How do I read a API document?

Tags: java, soap, paypal

I have been trying hard to make sense of this paypal stuff and yet I am stumped.

Studied this paypal API document but due to my limited Java knowledge I do not know how to use it.  Hope someone can advise me why my code went wrong.

Basically, I am trying to setExpressCheckOut the SOAP version which is compulsory in Java Paypal SOAP.

Here's the error code:

```
 SetExpressCheckoutRequestType requestType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
    requestType.set("94.0");
```

And the error message :

```
package requestType does not exist <identifier> expected
```

And here's the partial API document:

```
Constructor Summary

SetExpressCheckoutRequestType(DetailLevelCodeType[] detailLevel,
    java.lang.String errorLanguage,
    java.lang.String version,
    org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement[] _any,
    SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails)
```

Comment: Your question looks a bit weird to me. There is no API-Doc as stated, nor a link to one. The constructur you use in the code is not the same as stated at the bottom. The error message is in bad english, where does it come from? Where does the lib you are using come from?

Comment: Have you asked the PayPal support? They might be more proficient in answering questions on their API than SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading and using the new PayPal SDKs from here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Once you download the Java SDK, in the sample folder you will see the code that shows you how to create and send PayPal API requests.